# how to execute rake tasks from an ant script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ant, rake

i need to write an ant  (build.xml) file to do the following:
- run 'rake test'
- run 'rake rspec'
- run 'rake features'
- if all of the above pass, then do a 'cap deploy staging'

I am new to ant scripts, and so far, i have done:

```
<project name="myapp" basedir=".">
  <target name="run-migrations">
    <exec executable="rake">
      <arg value="db:migrate"></arg>
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="load-rake-task" depends="run-migrations">
    <exec executable="rake"></exec>
  </target>
  ...
</project>
```

This runs rake db:migrate, followed by rake, but i have not yet figured out how to capture the output of the running of the command, and better still, how to access if any of the tests failed.

How can i modify the above script to capture output and find out how many tests passed and failed in the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the output use the following attributes from `exec` task :

1. `outputproperty` for stdout
2. `errorproperty` for stderr
3. `resultproperty` for RC (returncode)

means something like that :

```
<exec executable="rake" outputproperty="rake.out" errorproperty="rake.err" resultproperty="rake.rc">
  <arg value="db:migrate"></arg>
</exec>
```

also it's recommended to use `failonerror="true"`, default is false.

see [Ant manual / exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) for the details.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how can i determine how many failures were there if any?

Comment: Never used rake. You may parse your properties ${rake.out} => catches rake stdout stream, ${rake.err} => catches rake stderr stream for specific patterns !?

Comment: so how can i modify the above exec command to do something like this:
if rake.out.match(/(\d+) errors/) && $1.to_i > 0, then
'output: there were $1 errors running rake, so aborting';
'fail'
else
'continue'

Comment: The usual approach would be to have your executable - some rake script in your case - provide appropriate error handling with printing the error summary and return some RC != 0 Thus you'll get the error summary in your ant log. When using failonerror="true" you will get a BUILD FAILED also. There are also try/catch/finally possiblities for ant if needed.